# How to Dynamically get column list from the Schema in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, jsonschema

Hi the schema s below: How can i get columns in a list in Pyspark.

[enter image description here][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAjmF.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYgUQ.png)

This is what schema look like

```
my_list = parsed_df.schema.fields
for field in my_list:
    print(field.name)
```

Comment: parsed_df.columns?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

Sample dataframe with struct

```
root
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
```

To get all columns into a list you below code

```
struct_fields = df2.schema['name'].dataType.fieldNames()
print("struct fields :",struct_fields)
print("columns without struct:", df2.columns)
final_columns = df2.columns + struct_fields
print("final columns: ", final_columns)
```

Output:

```
struct fields : ['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname']
columns without struct: ['name', 'state', 'gender']
final columns:  ['name', 'state', 'gender', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname']
```